# Uploading different pictures from same folder wit different names(all bmp) and processing them

Tags: matlab

I want to upload all images from 1 folder which have different names but all are bmp. I want to process them afterwards.How to upload them all and process them with 1 command?

The folder directory is `C:\Users\Gramoz\Desktop\Gramoz\140917` and the code I have to process them 1 by 1 is shown below(for a particular folder with the name of the image).

I just need the command for mutiupload and multiprocess for 1 folder,since the code can be unclear maybe.

```
fname = '103_Y(50)_Z(150)_EXP(8.159).bmp';
im = imread(fname);
figure(13)
imagesc(im)

C=max(max(im));
s=max(max(C));
[ROW COLUMN]=find(im==C);

row1 = ROW-17;
row2 = ROW+17;
col1 = COLUMN-17;
col2 = COLUMN+17;

Etot_min_BG = ( sum(sum(im))-(sum(sum(im(1:300,1:300)))/90000)*1024*1280);
Efoc = sum(sum(im(row1:row2,col1:col2)));
Efoc_min_BG = sum(sum(im(row1:row2,col1:col2))) - sum(sum(im(1:300,1:300)))/90000 * (row2-row1+1)*(col2-col1+1);


% =========================================================================
% =========================================================================


Nx = 1024; %Replace with real image dimensions 
Ny = 1280; %Replace with real image dimensions 
x0 = 451; %Replace with coordinate of MMF center
y0 = 644; %Replace with coordinate of MMF center
x = (1:Nx) - x0;
y = (1:Ny) - y0;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
X = X';
Y = Y';

% im = (X.^2+Y.^2).*exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/50); %Comment out this line, 
temp = imread(fname); %Uncomment this line, write real file name
h = 1/81*ones(9);
im = filter2(h,temp);
% im = zeros(64,80);
% for k = 1:128
%     for m = 1:160
%         im(k,m) = sum(sum(temp((1+(k-1)*8):(k*8) , (1+(m-1)*8):(m*8))));
%     end
% end


[temp1 temp2] = cart2pol(X, Y);

r = reshape(temp2, Nx*Ny,1);

theta = reshape(temp1, Nx*Ny,1);

impol = reshape(im, Nx*Ny,1);
% =========================================================================
% =========================================================================

% figure;
% imagesc(im);colorbar

% figure; 
% plot1=plot(r, impol, 'k.');
% xlabel('r [pix]');
% ylabel('Image value');
% set(gca, 'XLim', [0 350]);


% =========================================================================
% =========================================================================

% figure; 
% plot(theta, impol, 'k.');
% xlabel('theta [rad]');
% ylabel('Image value');

% =========================================================================
% =========================================================================


%=====bin data, r
numbins = 128;
% 
rbins = linspace(min(r), max(r), numbins);
[n rbin] = histc(r, rbins);
mu_r = full(mean(sparse(1:length(r),rbin,double(impol))));
figure;
plot(rbins, mu_r./rbins); %We divide by rbins to get the density in polar coordinates
xlabel('r_{bin} [pix]');
ylabel('Density');

% =========================================================================
% =========================================================================


%=====bin data, theta
thetabins = linspace(min(theta), max(theta), numbins);
[n thetabin] = histc(theta, thetabins);
mu_theta = full(mean(sparse(1:length(theta),thetabin,double(impol))));
% figure;
% plot(thetabins, mu_theta);
% xlabel('\theta_{bin} [rad]');
% ylabel('Density');


%  [Peakvalue Peakposition]=max(impol)]
%  r(Peakposition)
%  theta(Peakposition)
%  

% =========================================================================
% =========================================================================


{'  File name ','Peak value','Row of peak','Column of Peak','Etot_min_BG','Efoc','foc_min_BG';
  20 ,s,ROW,COLUMN,  Etot_min_BG  ,  Efoc  ,  Efoc_min_BG  }

% to find  r(max)
% plot(r,impol) ;
[M1 M2]=max(impol);
r=r(M2)

% to find theta(max)
% plot(theta,impol) ;
[M1 M2]=max(impol);
theta=theta(M2)

[M3 M4]=max(mu_r./rbins);
%  to fidn rdensity
% plot(rbins,mu_r./rbins) ; 
[M3 M4]=max(mu_r./rbins);
rdens=rbins(M4)

[M5 M6]=max(mu_theta);

% plot(thetabins, mu_theta);
[M5 M6]=max(mu_theta);
thetadens=thetabins(M6)

F=[ Etot_min_BG  Efoc  Efoc_min_BG r theta rdens thetadens ]
```

Comment: Encapsulate this in a `for` loop, then use `dir` to get a list of the images that you want.  Iterate over this list and load in each image one at a time, then proceed with your code.  I won't write an answer because I really don't know what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I am just summarising an answer based on **rayryeng** comment.
Since the only difference on you code should be the image, like was said above you just need to get the name of the files through the dir function and then loop over the different files.

As such you should have something like this:

```
images_names=dir(fullfile(images_path,'*.bmp'))
for i=1:length(images_names)
im = imread(fullfile(images_path,images_names(i).name));

%%% do your stuff here %%%%%%%%%%%%

%% if you need to save all in the same variable, and dont care how
save_F{i}=F; %%% like your F variable

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
end
```

Comment: Do I have to put all images names   at the    length(images_names)?

Comment: You just need to define the place where you have the images in the images_path. So if you have it on C:\images\ you just make, images_path='C:\images\'

Comment: The  saveF(i)=F is saving only 1 value.I need all of them,how to do it?

Comment: and I also have a problem at   temp = imread(fname);    the fname in my ancient code is the name of the image,how should it be in the new code to make it work,with what should I change fname,since with images_names it doesnt work